How to describe a living room having a balcony door letting you view the city down below? Can I say "a room with an open layout"?
layout: the way something is designed or arranged
If my living room has a balcony door letting me view the city down below, can I call it "a room with an open layout"? If not, how would you concisely refer to such a room?

An "open layout" is typically used of rooms that open onto or blend into other rooms without a doorway between them, not of rooms with a door that opens out onto a balcony. A house with an open layout might have a family room in one side of the room rectangle and a kitchen on the other half of the room rectangle, separated by a large kitchen island.

You could say "a room with a view".

@WeatherVane Would you picture that room with a balcony?

The balcony doors open out onto a view of the city. The room is not relevant.

An "open layout" or more usually "open plan" describes the interior of a room which might, for example, blend a dining area with a kitchen, known as a "kitchen diner" or even transitioning into a lounge area as well.
The best way of describing your room is probably

A room with a balcony affording views of the city.

This is a form of words (jargon) often employed by UK estate agents and other professionals when describing property, particularly when the view is supposedly pleasing. "Affording a view" implies something to be desired whilst "overlooking" could be anything from a spacious park to the local abattoir.
Although it is architecturally possible to have interior balconies, a native English speaker would understand this to be an exterior balcony from the context - it is unlikely you would be able to see the cityscape from an interior one.

What about "a room overlooking the city", or more precisely "a room with a balcony overlooking the city"? They're a bit shorter.

@AnIELTSLearner Yes you could also say either of those.

You could say

A room with a balcony view.

which tells you the room has two things: a balcony, and a view. When I searched for balcony view this set of images (captions removed) was shown:

images from Google
There are many kinds of balcony: some may improve the view, others restrict it. Some aren't balconies at all: a Juliet balcony often has no balcony at all, being basically a guard rail to stop you falling through the doors.

I find your version really concise. I wonder why it hasn't received many upvotes.

A Juliet balcony can also be called a "balconette".

@AndyB Or indeed a French balcony.

OP has enquired

If my living room has a balcony door letting me view the city down below, can I call it "a room with an open layout"?   If not, how would you concisely refer to such a room?

"Open layout" fails to convey your intention:

An open floor plan is a design approach that embraces large open spaces and minimizes the use of dividing walls and enclosed rooms.
https://www.roomsketcher.com/blog/open-floor-plan/

There are many ways to express yourself, but this would be perfect if you want to draw attention to something or develop a marketing pitch:
"Room featuring a balcony with panoramic city view.".
Or concisely
"Room with stunning city views"

I'm going to guess that you are referring not to a regular balcony, in which there is a platform outside the room with access from (in this case) your living room, but to the kind of door which opens to the outside and has a railing across it but no platform outside (or sometimes a very narrow platform). Something like this:

That feature is called a "Juliet balcony".

Or, as noted under the other answer, a French balcony or a balconette.
